# How to design object oriented subparsers for argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, argparse

### Problem

I'm building a package manager that has a lot of sub-commands. I would prefer to have a class structure similar to the following.

```py
class ListCommand:
  def __init__(self):
    name = "list"
    alias = "ls"
    short_description = "A useful simple line that explains the command"

  def help(self):
    # Display help

  def command(self):
    # do stuff when command is called
```

How do I write subparser to work with something like this ? I found an [example](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/03/21/python-multilevel-argparse.html) online that does something similar without subparsers.

Comment: First play around with `subparsers` as described in the documentation. Include the `set_defaults` trick.  I suspect that once you've done that for several subparsers, you'll see how to generate those subparsers from your class.  If you get stuck add an example parser to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cmd class and parser:

```
import argparse

class Cmd:
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

  def __call__(self, args):
    # do stuff when command is called
    print('Executing %s'%self)
    print('args %s'% args)

  def make_sup(self,sp):
      self.parser = sp.add_parser(self.name)
      self.parser.add_argument('--foo')
      self.parser.set_defaults(action=self)

  def __repr__(self):
      return '<Cmd> %s'%self.name

cmds = []
cmds.append(Cmd('list'))
cmds.append(Cmd('foo'))
cmds.append(Cmd('bar'))
print(cmds)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
for cmd in cmds:
    cmd.make_sup(sp)
print(parser._defaults)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
args.action(args)
```

sample runs:

```
1834:~/mypy$ python stack46595691.py list --foo xxxx
[<Cmd> list, <Cmd> foo, <Cmd> bar]
{}
Namespace(action=<Cmd> list, cmd='list', foo='xxxx')
Executing <Cmd> list
args Namespace(action=<Cmd> list, cmd='list', foo='xxxx')
1837:~/mypy$ python stack46595691.py bar
[<Cmd> list, <Cmd> foo, <Cmd> bar]
{}
Namespace(action=<Cmd> bar, cmd='bar', foo=None)
Executing <Cmd> bar
args Namespace(action=<Cmd> bar, cmd='bar', foo=None)
1838:~/mypy$ python stack46595691.py foo -h
[<Cmd> list, <Cmd> foo, <Cmd> bar]
{}
usage: stack46595691.py foo [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO
```

You might also want to look at `plac`, a package that subclasses `ArgumentParser`, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac

It can construct subparsers based on the arguments of functions.